# relative pronoun omitted

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

I came across a sentence

> ReWalk was created by Argo’s founder, Amit Goffer, himself quadriplegic as the result of a 1997 ATV accident.

"Who is" is omitted in it. Does that mean I can use similar sentences like

> This cake is eaten by him (who is) happy.
>
> He solved a problem (which is) difficult.

I am not native speaker but they sound strange to me.

Can (relative pronoun+ be verb) be omitted in that structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a shrewd guess, but as you suspected neither of these sentences is idiomatic.

This sort of ellipsis (called *Whiz-deletion*, a jocular contraction of *wh- is*) has an ancillary "rule": if only a *single* adjective is left after the deletion it must be moved in front of the noun:

> <sup>∗</sup>He solved a problem <s>which was</s> difficult  ⇨ <sup>ok</sup>He solved a difficult problem.

But you can't do this with *him*, because personal pronouns cannot take attributive adjectives (except in certain exclamations):

> <sup>∗</sup>The cake is eaten by him happy  ⇨ <sup>∗</sup>The cake is eaten by happy him.

It should be pointed out that neither of the sentences you put forward is natural in English, with or without the deletion. The *problem* sentence would never be uttered, because the natural way of saying this is with the ordinary preposed attributive: *He solved a difficult problem*. And *him who is happy* is a very literary construction; *the happy man/guy/fellow* is the natural way of saying this. Better examples would be something like these:

> The cake was eaten by someone <s>who was</s> happy to find it.
>   He solved a problem <s>which was</s> too difficult for me.

Moreover, it is not clear that the *himself quadriplegic* phrase at the end of the first sentence should be regarded as a relative clause. It is clearly a supplement or afterthought, and I would be happier understanding it as an [appositive](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Appositive-Adjective.htm).